# Angular jhipster <ng-select>

Tags: angular6, jhipster, angular-ngselect

I'm developing an app using Jhipster where I'm trying to show a `<ng-select>`, that is not rendering  as the [attached file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFhaP.jpg), I have also included the default theme (`@import "~@ng-select/ng-select/themes/default.theme.css"`) in vendor.css and have rebuilt everything, it's not displayed too. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you add the required [items] input ?

Comment: Yes, I added it as an array from the TypeScript code, for example: public items:Array<string> = ['Amsterdam', 'Antwerp', 'Athens', 'Barcelona', 'Berlin'].

Comment: I tried to reproduce the issue with the newest version of Angular and it looks like I got the same problem as you. If you need a solution fast, can Ng Bootstrap Typeahead component satisfy your needs?

Comment: Yes, I did that, with the Typeahead worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue as you and I solved it. 
This is not an issue related to , but to any library you want to use.
To be able to add any thrid party library, you should follow the way jhipster is doing.
1- Create a module where to add the libraries module in import and export sections
2- Add this module (in import and export sections) to the shared.module.ts module.

A good example is here: https://medium.com/@cyril.casaucau/how-to-add-angular-material-on-an-jhipster-5-x-app-97c9569c9f97

**Or simply add the NgSelectModule module to shared-libs.module.ts file.**

Comment: From Review: Hi, while links are great way of sharing knowledge, they won't really answer the question if they get broken in the future. Add to your answer the essential content of the link which answers the question. In case the content is too complex or too big to fit here, describe the general idea of the proposed solution. Remember to always keep a link reference to the original solution's website. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)